# Hangs on file upload

Tags: devdemon-updater

I'm running a brand-new install of EE 3.3.4 and DevDemon's Updater 4.0. When I try to upload an add-on ZIP file through Updater, it allows me to select a file but then just hangs at the 'uploading, please wait...' message.

No error message is presented, but I did check for Javascript errors and found that the following pops up when submitting a file for upload:

```
ReferenceError: Spinner is not defined
xhr2Upload()
    addon_mcp.js:114
dialogClosed()
    addon_mcp.js:54
Z.event.dispatch()
    jquery.js:3
Z.event.add/m.handle()
    jquery.js:3
```

Any ideas on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it happened (or why it took me so long to think of it), but apparently at least one of the theme files didn't get uploaded correctly. I re-uploaded the whole themes directory and all is well now.